# Pointwise estimation of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Suppose $k_1$ and $k_2$ are bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose further that $k_2$ is smooth and compactly supported. Defined another function $k_3$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by

$$k_3(x,z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}k_1(x,y)k_2(y,z)\,dy.$$

**Question:** If $k_1$ satisfies the estimate

$$|k_1(x,y)|\leq e^{-|x-y|}$$

for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, does it follow that $k_3$ satisfies an estimate of the form
$$|k_3(x,z)|\leq Ce^{-D|x-z|}$$
for some constants $C$ and $D$?

*Background*: This question came from trying to estimate the composition of two Schwartz kernels $k_1$ and $k_2$, but it has just been phrased for $\mathbb{R}$ instead of the general scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$\int_\mathbb{R} k_1(x,y)k_2(y,z)\,dy\leq\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-|x-y|}k_2(y,z)\,dy.$$
Since $|x-z|\leq|x-y|+|y-z|$, we have
$$e^{-|x-y|}\leq e^{-(|x-z|-|y-z|)}.$$
Thus the above integral is
$$\leq\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-(|x-z|-|y-z|)}k_2(y,z)\,dy=e^{-|x-z|}\int_L e^{|y-z|}k_2(y,z)\,dy\leq Ce^{-|x-z|},$$
where $L$ is some compact subset and $C$ a constant.